# PHP MySQL Operadores y Varibales

Tags: php, variables, operador

Quiero hacer que el usuario capture algunos valores que incluyen operadores de comparación, por decir algo.

```
Campo Valor: El usuario captura 90
Campo Verde: El usuario captura >=80
Campo Amarillo: El usuairo captura >=70
Campo Rojo: El usuario captura <=75
```

Esos datos al darle enviar pasan a otra página que haga una serie de compraciones, por ejemplo:

```
<?php 


if ($_POST['Valor'] $_POST['Verde']){

    $tuvalores= "100"
}
elseif ($_POST['Valor'] $_POST['Amarillo'] || $_POST['Valor'] $_POST['Rojo']){

    $tuvalores= "85"
}
else{

    $tuvalores = "70"

}

echo "Tu estas en: " . $tuvalores . " por ciento."


?>
```

Es decir que los campos capturados tomen los valores completos, o sea:

```
si 90 >= 85 entonces es 100
si 90 >= 70 y <=75 es 85
si no entonces es 70.

Tu estas en: 100 por ciento.
```

¿Es posible llevarlo acabo así?, o ¿Se tendría que hacer por separado los operadores y los valores?

Espero haber sido claro en lo que trato de realizar, ya lo intente pero me da:

**error: syntax error, unexpected '$_POST' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ',' or ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\encuesta.php on line 4**

Ya busque algunas otras alternativas pero solo encuentro cocatenar o operadores lógicos y obviamente no me da el resultado que estoy buscando.

Gracias de antemano por su apoyo.

Comment: Deberías añadir el fragmento de código exacto donde ocurre el error de tu pregunta

Comment: Esta parte esta mal: `if ($_POST['Valor'] $_POST['Verde']){`, pues no veo por ningún lado alguna comparación que indique una condición a cumplir entre los 2 valores

Comment: BetaM ya lo agregue y actualice el error. Gracias

Comment: @BetaM no aparecen tal cual ya que según yo lo que busco es que el usuario capture el operador junto con el valor, es decir : >=80 y así tal cual pase por POST el operador y el valor al mismo tiempo y se haga las comparaciones digamos que dinámicamente.

Comment: BetaM, Pero de hacerlo así en lo cual estoy de acuerdo tendría que generar una serie de IF para que pueda hacer las compraciones, ya que por ejemplo el usuario en vez de capturar >=80 podría poner solo =80 o capturar <80, por eso pensanba que se podría hacer de forma dinámica.

Comment: ¿Por qué ocupas en tu if esto así? if ( $_POST['Valor'] $_POST['Verde'] ) Eso está incorrecto!

Comment: @FernandoTorres en efecto es lo que me provoca el error pero como comentaba lo que quiero es que se tome de formsa dínamica el valor completo, en el campo el usuairo deberá capturar esto así >=80 y pensaba en que se pudiera pasar directo esto por post y hacerlo dinámico en vez de meter una serie de IF's para hacer tantas comparaciones, pero por lo que veo al parecer no hay forma de hacerl dinámico.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despúes de buscar diferentes formas ví que no es posible hacer lo que tenia pensado,

No se puede simplemente porque no hay forma de obtener un campo tipo string que contenga los operadores lógicos junto con el valor a comparar y esto se haga de forma directa. ejemplo: - campo1: >=5 -.

Gracias por las respuestas.